# WPF:Unity: Reuse window after it has been closed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container

In ShellViewModel I have below command binding to open a new window "Remote View"

```
public ICommand RemoteViewCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(RemoteViewExecute, CanRemoteViewExecute); }
}

private void RemoteViewExecute()
{
    if (!CanRemoteViewExecute())
    {
        return;
    }


    var shellRemoteView = Application._Container.Resolve<ShellRemoteView>();
    if (_ShellRemoteView.DataContext==null)
        _ShellRemoteView.DataContext = Application._Container.Resolve<ShellRemoteViewModel>();        

    shellRemoteView.Show();
}
```

On startup I have already registered both "ShellRemoteView" and "ShellRemoteViewModel" using lifetime managers to have singleton instance.

```
_Container.RegisterType<ShellRemoteView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_Container.RegisterType<ShellRemoteViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

When shellRemoteView.Show() executed and I close the form, then again on calling shellRemoteView.Show() I'm getting **Invalid Operation excepton:Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.**

Is there is any work-around in Unity **to get window instance again if its closed**.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
return new RelayCommand(RemoteViewExecute, CanRemoteViewExecute);
```

Basically you are creating a new view each time you call the Get command.  The way to fix this is to put a variable outside your GET statement that is scoped at the ViewModel level.  Have it store a reference to the view and return that reference instead of creating a new reference each time.  Look at the [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) for how best to do this.

Comment: you mean this?   
private ICommand _remoteViewCommand;
        public ICommand RemoteViewCommand
        {
            get { return _remoteViewCommand ?? (_remoteViewCommand = new RelayCommand(RemoteViewExecute, CanRemoteViewExecute)); }            
            }
        } this doesnt help. I was actually looking for a way to do through unity.

Comment: @Andy - Not sure what you mean by "through Unity" (not really familiar with most of Unity).  Does this link help?  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/20949/singleton-implementation.html

Comment: Thanks for that really appreciate your help. 
Unity I meant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608585/can-someone-explain-microsoft-unity

Answer (score 0):

You should register your View with [LifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.lifetimemanager%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) to create only one instance. Look at [Using Lifetime Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648098.aspx).