# The current type, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why it is not working?

This is my controller.

```
public class OperatorsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IOperatorService userService;
    public OperatorsController(IOperatorService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should explore the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549156/exception-is-invalidoperationexception-the-current-type-is-an-interface-and). You likely have forgotten to map `IOperatorService` to a concrete class in your Unity container.