# C# winforms shared mysql connection over projects

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create only one instance over all my projects in solution. I want top prevent multiple database objects.

I have this organisation on project:

```
|-Solution:
|--- Core 
|-------- Common
|------------ App.cs <singleton>
|------------ Model.cs
|------------ Database.cs
|
|--- Project 1
|-------- Models
|------------- Users.cs
|------------- Products.cs
|------------- Categories.cs
|-------- UI
|-------- etc...
|
|--- Project 2
|--- Project 3
|--- Project 4
```

`Core` project is library project which has `App` singleton class, `Model` class is base class for models and database class for `MySql`.

Base Model:

```
namespace Core.Common
{
    public class Model : Database
    {
        public Database db;

        public Model()
        {
            db = new Database();

            if(db.IsConnected())
            {
                App.IsConnected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in all my models i create this:

```
namespace Core.Models
{
    public class Products: Model
    {

        public Products() : base()
        {
            //..etc  
        }


        public DataTable ShowAll()
        {
            return db.query("SELECT * FROM products");
        }
    }
}
```

So all my project has models for database and model must extend base model class wich already contain database object for connecting. But all models class must extend `base` construcotr for establishing connection.

But am thinking this is litle bad practice.

What about to create object for database inside `Main()`? than will be globaly over priject right ?

Any other approach to improve this project?

Comment: yeah it looks bad. use DI through method parameter instead of creating for every model.

Comment: hm in all my model methods to inject Database class is better right

Comment: i would recommend using unity here. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/608617/2745294

Comment: all you want to access database through multiple models right. better to use unity & may be create in main method. try this one IOC approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532254/2745294

Comment: So Di in constructor is best

Comment: ivan, for starters lets try DI approch through constructor.. DI or IOC both has pros n cons.

Comment: But what when i create new object for `Product` model so i must assign database object `new Product(new Database)... I must learn more about container. Thanks for answers guys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116865/discussion-between-sushil-mate-and-ivan).